# Find the possible eigenvalues of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a space $V$ of dimension $n$. Suppose there are $V_0,...,V_n$ of $V$ such that $\text{dim}(V_i)=i$ for all $i$ and $T(V_i)\subset V_{i-1}$ for all $i\geq 1$. What are the possible eigenvalues of $T$? When is $T$ diagonalizable?

My try: By definition, we know that $V_0=\{0\}$ and thus $T(V_1)=\{0\}$. Hence, $0$ is one of the eigenvalues of $T$. But how to find other eigenvalues?

Comment: *Hint:* You don't.

Comment: @Gae.S. You mean there is no other eigenvalue?

Comment: @copper.hat The assumption is $T(V_i)\subset V_{i-1}$ which may be stronger than dim $T(V_{i-1}\leq i-1$.

Comment: @whereamI: I deleted my comments which were misleading & incorrect. The essence of the above (which I was slow in picking up on) is that $T^n(V_n) = V_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T(V_1)=0$, $T^{n+1}=0, T(x)=cx$ implies $T^{n+1}(x)=c^{n+1}x=0, c=0$.

Comment: Thank you. So the characteristic polynomial is $\mu(x)=x^n$. But how to make sure that $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: $T$ is diagonalizable implies that there exists a basis of eigenvectors, since $0$ is the only eigenvalue, we deduce that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $T=0$.

Comment: $T$ is nilpotent. It is then not diagonalizable, unless $T=0$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide Gotcha. Thank you very much.